# Data Mining Query in Data Flow

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssis

I have created a package using SSIS 2012 that uses data mining query & runs perfectly well in SQL Server Data Tools.

The problem is that it does not finish running when scheduled on SQL Agent. The package runs about 60 seconds in data tools and it never finishes when scheduled.

I have enabled logging but nothing is logged while running as a job.

Please advise.

**Update 1:**

Error message: To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install Pivot of Integration Services or higher.

**Update 2:**

Package ran by setting delay validation to true on data mining query.
However, the job on sql agent runs in funny way every second job takes 12 minutes to run while every other one takes 1 minute to run.

Comment: DBA rebooted the server that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have the SSIS bits installed on that machine. Find your installation media and click back through the install process. Ensure that you have selected the SQL Server Integration Services Service (isn't that a mouthful).

- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49786/error-to-run-a-ssis-package-outside-of-sql-server-data-tools-you-must-install
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36915/ssis-recordset-destination-error

Comment: Oh anonymous downvoter, (hi [@TheOptimusPrime](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2517150/theoptimusprimus)) could you help me understand the downvote so that I may improve this answer?